# j and k keys not working like they should

Tags: cursor-movement, key-bindings, microsoft-windows

I'm using gVim on my Windows 8.1 computer with a standard QWERTY keyboard, and neither the <kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>k</kbd> keys, nor the <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Down</kbd> arrow keys let me move up and down in my text field while in normal mode. <kbd>h</kbd> and <kbd>l</kbd> for left/right work fine.

The behaviour of up and down is somewhat sporadic. Sometimes it doesn't work at all. Other times, like right now, it jumps from the top of the file to the bottom of the file. The cursor never jumps higher than the last position it was at when going up, and it always goes to the bottom left when going down.

I used `map` to check for custom mappings, which said 'no mapping found'. I also tried starting without a vimrc file, and that didn't fix it.

How do I find out why and fix it?

Comment: I'm using a standard qwerty layout. Just now tried starting without vimrc and the problem persists. Looked for mapping and it says no mapping found. You are correct, left and right work just fine. The behavior of up and down is somewhat sporadic. Sometimes it doesn't work at all. Other times, like right now, it jumps from the top of the file to the bottom of the file. The cursor never jumps higher than the last position it was at when going up,  and it always goes to the bottom left when going down.

Comment: You might then try `:verbose :nmap j` to see if something else happened to clear it (this should say what last set `:nmap j`). Also, do `gj` and `gk` work? What if you enter visual mode first (type `v`) and then hit `j`, `k`, or `gj`, `gk`, or `<UP>`, `<DOWN>`?

Comment: OK, verbose still yields no mapping found. Interestingly enough, gj and gk work in both normal and visual mode. Why is that?

Comment: Just fixed it. Not sure why it doesn't work, but your advice about gj and gk gave me something to go on, and I found how to reverse Map the keys so that I can go line be line with just j and k And just several lines with gj and gk. Thank you so much! @mixedmath

Comment: It sounds like your file might be just a single line. In Vim, `k` and `j` go up and down one actual line, rather than one visible line. If your line wraps at 80 characters, and you have 100 characters, that is one line to Vim, even though it is displayed as two lines. `gk` and `gj` use display lines rather than actual lines, which is more in line (no pun intended) with what gui-based text editors do.

Comment: Ah. Didn't know that. I am following along with a tutorial and I copied and pasted a paragraph from the PDF. So I suppose that could lose it's formatting in the crossover. I'll test for that. Changing back will be real easy. :-)

Comment: Somebody should make that an answer...

Comment: This started happening to me out of the blue on msys2 for windows, h and l and j and k jump a random amount up and down between 9 and 90 increments. no vimrc file. no mapping, no verbose mapping.

Comment: the same vim binary and file works fine on the same host over remote/ssh, its just on the mingw shell that it is super broken

Comment: restarting the host helped, it might have to do with resizing the msys2 terminal emulator